How to script a physical to VHDX backup for use as a Hyper-V VM
I want to script a backup of my computer into a VHDX file for use as a VM in case something crashes irreparably and I cannot recover the windows installation. My computer has 2 disks, a typical "main" with 3 volumes (C:, ?\volume{819..., ?\volume{d89..., one being the EFI, and the other being the recovery), and then a second disk (D:) for just extra storage.  I want to create a VHDX for just the first disk, I don't need to backup the D:.
I am aware of disk2vhd, but per How to call disk2vhd to create a VHDX for use as a VM and exlcude the D: drive, it doesn't seem that there is a way to script a VHDX creation with the inclusion of the C: and boot volume without also including the D:, and I simply don't have enough space to create one giant VHDX with all of them.
What other free/opensource tools can be used to script + automation a backup like this?
